# Get value from a function that was added to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, callback

This is a code in document ready

```
 $(document).ready(function {

 $('button[id$="btnSave"]').click(function() {
        saveEvent();
    });

    function saveEvent() {
        $.colorbox.close();
        result = { date: $('#txtDate').val(), description: $('#txtDescription').val() }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Here is where I need this results

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    disableResizing: true,
    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            $('#loading').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    },
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {


        displayInput($(this), date);// show modal

   //!!return results from modal on mouse click!!

    },
    events: {
        url: 'UserCalendarService.asmx/GetEvents',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',            
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
});
```

This works fine, but how can I get this result object in other function when I click on the Save button. For example, When Colorbox modal is showed, user click on the save button. How can I get return value of saveEvent function at that time?

Later on I'll need a callback to put this user values in calendar ui

Comment: where do you want to use the result of saveEvent function?

Comment: This is just a simple example. Result would be send via ajax to web service, but I will also show them in some calendar ui on the page

Answer (score 1):

It seems simple - see comment below.

```
 $(document).ready(function {

 $('button[id$="btnSave"]').click(function() {
        var returnValue=saveEvent();
        //SEND return value anywhere you want.
    });

    function saveEvent() {
        $.colorbox.close();
        result = { date: $('#txtDate').val(), description: $('#txtDescription').val() }
        return result;
    }
});
```